# Chrome Extension Page Action Codes

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome Extension that shows specific codes/text depending on which site you are on. So, for example, let's say that you are on www.facebook.com then the code "hello", "bye" and "what" will show up then let's say that we go to www.youtube.com then different codes will appear depending on what I have in my JSON file.

I have no idea how to accomplish this so far I have managed to only make the extension work on the sites I want it to work on. This is how I believe the problem will be solved somehow with that. I have also created a "box" that will hold this code/text [Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF1rt.png)

My manifest code: 
`{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chahching",
    "version": "1.0",

```
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
       "16": "images/icon16.png",
       "24": "images/icon24.png",
       "32": "images/icon32.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Chaching"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.g2a.com/*", "https://www.kinguin.net/*"],
        "js": ["content.js", "jquery.js"]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://www.g2a.com/*",
    "https://www.kinguin.net/*"
]
```

The HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="couponbg">
            <div class="couponinfo">
                <div id="unique-code">BRG</div>
                <div id="description"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
    {
    "www.g2a.com": [
        {
            "codes": ["BRG", "makehoney", "test1", "test2"],
            "deals": ["https://www.g2a.com/best-deals/weeklysale?banner=main"]
        }
    ]
}
```